# Bootstrap Carousel - Botão cobre o slide inteiro

Tags: carousel, slide

[image: a busy cat]

Estou utilizando o Carousel do Bootstrap mas quando eu pauso o vídeo ele vai para a esqueda, os quadrados pretos da imagem é pra mostrar que está "cobrindo", gostaria que ficasse somente na seta e não no slide inteiro.

Comment: O que q vai pra esquerda? Não entendi essa parte.

Comment: Giselle está difícil de entender o problema. Vc poderia postar o seu código. Tanto o HTML, quanto o CSS se estiver usando algo além do CSS do Boostrap por favor